# How to determine reserves from getReserves method on Uniswap pair

Tags: web3js, uniswap

I have a bunch of incoming `WETH` pairs that I am calling:

```
const reserves = await uPair.methods.getReserves().call()
```

My understanding is that `getReserves()` will output the reserves based on the order the tokens of the pair are input to the function. However, I am wondering how that works when calling `getReserves()` on a pair like I am doing above.

If I am getting `token0` and `token1` from the pair. Does that mean that `token0` would match `reserves0`. Then the same thing for `token1` and `reserves1`?

Lastly, I am getting outputs like the following:

```
Token0: 0x8E84f5B87F29c512c25026bF3169d134351c3Ba5
Token1: 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2
Pair: 0x8230F1f18FCB1Ca08BE63CFfe543F710a737f53A
Reserves 0: 399999999999999999999999
Reserves 1: 1000000000000000000
```

If my understanding is correct. `Reserves1` would match `token1` and that would mean that there is `1 ETH` for the `WETH` side of the pairing and it looks like reserves are being returned in `WEI`. What I do not understand is why are the decimals different between the two tokens? I am pretty new to this, but I would have thought that if it is a `WETH` pairing they would be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Token0: 0x8E84f5B87F29c512c25026bF3169d134351c3Ba5
Token1: 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2
Pair: 0x8230F1f18FCB1Ca08BE63CFfe543F710a737f53A
Reserves 0: 399999999999999999999999
Reserves 1: 1000000000000000000
```

[Token0](https://etherscan.io/token/0x8e84f5b87f29c512c25026bf3169d134351c3ba5) has 9 decimals
[Token1](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2) has 18 decimals

since there is no float on EVM, decimals is just an indicator to see where you should put your `.`, in this case token0 is 9th position from the end, and token1 18th position from the end.

- Token0: 399999999999999.999999999 POISON
- Token1: 1.000000000000000000 Ether

Comment: Thank you for the response. This makes sense. However, could you please explain how would I detect this programmatically? Thank you!

Comment: Also, am I right by assuming that `Token0` would match `reserves0`?

Comment: Yes, token0 -> reserves0 and token1 -> reserves1

Comment: sorry not sure to understand your question what do you want to detect programmatically?

Comment: Sorry I guess I could have explained better. The ultimate goal would be to know how much liquidity would be in the pairing. The `WETH` side being pretty easy as I can see what the price of 1 ETH is. However, I am not sure what to do with `399999999999999.999999999 POISON`. Do you know if  Uniswap offers a way to check the amount of liquidity within a pair and if so how to do this programmatically?

Comment: the amount of liquidity is `399999999999999.999999999` POISON + 
`1` ETHER. Again I'm not sure to understand, this is actually returning the amount of liquidity

Comment: Okay, so would that mean that `399999999999999.999999999 POISON` = `1 ETH`?

Comment: exactly ! But you can't swap `1 ETH` for `399999999999999.999999999 POISON` because of the slippage and the low liquidity the price impact will be close to 99%,

but if you had had enough liquidity, let's say `1000 ETH` for `399999999999999999.999999000`(1000x times more), it would have been possible to exchange `1eth` for `399999999999999.999999999`

Comment: This makes a ton of sense! Thank you!